# Ruby string structure

Tags: ruby, string

I am attempting to create a string using:

```
puts '["#{follower.screen_name}"]'
```

I want the output to be

```
["DailySanJose"]
```

where `DailySanJose` is the value of `follower.screen_name`. However, the current output is

```
["#{follower.screen_name}"]
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Question is not clear. `puts` does not create (return) a string. Do you want to create or output a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interpolation (`#{}`) only works in double quoted strings.

Try this:

```
puts "[\"#{follower.screen_name}\"]"
```

I'm including the double quotes in the string by *escaping* them with the `\` (backslash) character.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a %Q to not have to worry about escaping quotes

such as

```
%Q(["#{follower.screen_name}"])
```

This will escape the quotes for you automatically and do the string interpolation, that way you don't have to worry about it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to make something like JSON output:

```
require 'json'

test = "DailySanJose"

JSON.dump([ test ])
# => "[\"DailySanJose\"]"
```

The advantage here is this accounts for strings like `The "Test"` which requires double quoting. Don't be confused by the `\"` part, as when you print that it comes out exactly as-is:

```
puts JSON.dump([ test ])
# => ["DailySanJose"]
```

There's also a few other simple ways:

```
[ test ].inspect
# => "[\"DailySanJose\"]"
```

Comment: This does work. It's worth mentioning, however, that the output of `inspect` is not considered reliable, and shouldn't be used for anything besides debugging. Using JSON is much better.

Comment: @Linuxios How is `inspect` not reliable? It's fundamental to Ruby and when using plain strings it works great. I agree that JSON is a better call if that's the intended goal, as the output is a lot more standardized.

Comment: I don't know about the reliability of the method, but pp would print a much nicer string representation of a larger data structure.

Comment: @StephenCarman `pp` depends on a subjective definition of "pretty", so that might not meet the requirements here. JSON's output is extremely consistent and standards based.

Comment: @tadman well, yes, beauty is in the eye of the beholder :-) I was just suggesting additional options and I think it's prettier. :-)

Comment: @StephenCarman Options are great! I'm just concerned that someone could have configured `pp` to output something different, or introduce ANSI color.

Comment: @tadman: Reliable was the wrong word. I just meant that it's better not to use `inspect` for something it really isn't meant for. When I said reliable, I was thinking of the fact that there's no reason why `[1, 2, 3].inspect` would be `"[1,2,3]"` now, but become `"Array at 0x000003453: [1,2,3]"` in some later version of Ruby, or in another implementation (JRuby, IronRuby, etc.).

Comment: @Linuxios That is a good point, and I can't disagree with that.

Comment: @tadman: Sorry if it came across at first as a little bit forceful :).

Comment: @Linuxios Not at all. I don't mind advice with a solid basis, but the first thing you said sounded vaguely like paranoia or cargo-cult thinking. I've re-ordered the suggestions in my answer to account for that.

Answer (score 0):

To round out the options, you could also use a [heredoc](http://rubyquicktips.com/post/4438542511/heredoc-and-indent):

```
howdy = "hi"
puts <<_
["#{howdy}"]
_
  # ["hi"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use puts '["'+follower.screen_name+'"]'

Answer (score -1):

**Edit**

you can do it this way with double quotes

```
puts %{["#{follower.screen_name}"]}
```

Comment: This will work, but it doesn't generate the desired output, which must contain double quotes, according to the OP.

Comment: @Linuxios, you are saying, "This will work but it doesn't work." :-) Strike "will work, but it"?